# A closed form for $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(nx\right)}}{\sin{x}}\right)^{2p}\,\mathrm{d}x} $?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

For $ n,p\in\mathbb{N} $, define $ I_{p}\left(n\right) $ as follows : $$ I_{p}\left(n\right)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(\frac{\sin{\left(nx\right)}}{\sin{x}}\right)^{2p}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

A closed form can be found for $ I_{0}\left(n\right) $, $ I_{1}\left(n\right) $ and $ I_{2}\left(n\right) $, for any $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, we have the following identities : \begin{aligned} I_{0}\left(n\right)&=\frac{\pi}{2} \\I_{1}\left(n\right)&=\frac{n\pi}{2} \\I_{2}\left(n\right)&=\frac{n\pi\left(2n^{2}+1\right)}{6}\end{aligned}

Can we generalise the result for all $ p\in\mathbb{N} $ ?

Comment: Could you add what you have done so far......it could give a good point to start.

Comment: @metamorphy I'm sorry, there was a mistake in the statement, but I just corrected it.

Comment: You know that $\forall\text{p}$, when $\text{n}=1$, we get: $$\mathcal{I}_\text{p}\left(1\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @Jan yes I noticed.

Comment: I think $I_1(n)-I_1(n-1)\approx\frac{\pi}{2}$. The larger the value of $n$ the better the approximation seems to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, we have $\int_0^{\pi/2}=\frac12\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$. Substituting $z=e^{2\mathrm{i}x}$, we get (using the "coefficient-of" notation) $$I_p(n)=\frac{1}{4\mathrm{i}}\oint_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}\right)^{2p}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^{(n-1)p+1}}=\frac{\pi}{2}[z^{(n-1)p}](1+z+\ldots+z^{n-1})^{2p}.$$ For a fixed $p$, a closed form is easy to obtain. But for a fixed $n$, even the case $n=3$ is [hard enough](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html).

Comment: I can elaborate the case of fixed $p$ if needed (it would involve a double recurrence, but it allows to handle cases of small $p$ in a pretty mechanical way). The main point is that there's no hope to get a closed form for an *arbitrary* $p$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: cant we think of using 2nd type of chebyshev polynomials ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use somme proprieties of Fejér Kernel. So we have:
$$F_n(2x)=\frac{1}{n}\biggl(\frac{\sin (nx)}{\sin x}\biggr)^2=\sum_{k=-n}^n\biggl(1-\frac{|k|}{n}\biggr)e^{2ikx}$$
Then we have,
$$I_p(n)=n\sum_{k_1=-n}^n\sum_{k_2=-n}^n...\sum_{k_p=-n}^n\prod_{j=1}^p\biggl(1-\frac{|k_j|}{n}\biggr)\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{2xi\sum_{j=1}^pk_j}dx$$
Therefore we get,
$$I_p(n)=n\sum_{k_1=-n}^n\sum_{k_2=-n}^n...\sum_{k_p=-n}^n\prod_{j=1}^p\biggl(1-\frac{|k_j|}{n}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{(-1)^{\sum_{j=1}^pk_j}-1}{2i\sum_{j=1}^pk_j}\biggr)$$
For more information about Fejér Kernel see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you too for this good exercise