# Integrating powers of the Fejer kernel

Tags: combinatorics, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fejer-kernel

In attempting to solve a combinatorics problem (number of ways of rolling $2n$ $k$-sided dice and getting the median sum), I reduced things to finding the constant term the Laurent series for $(f(z)f(1/z))^n$ where $f(z)=\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}$ for some (unspecified) $n,k\in \mathbb N$.  One can compute this as a contour integral over a circle containing the origin, e.g.,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{z^{k/2}-z^{-k/2}}{z^{1/2}-z^{-1/2}}\right)^{2n}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{1-\cos(x)}\right)^ndx.$$

However, I do not know how to evaluate this integral (and neither does WolframAlpha, at least not for generic $n,k$). Is there perhaps a reduction formula that one could use to tackle the problem? Or was converting the problem from combinatorics to integration not the right approach to begin with?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3676494) (actually looks *the same*).

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, it is.  Though the answers there tell me that (1) the cobinatorial approach is better than the integration approach and (2) the combinatorial approach is absolutely abysmal.  It looks like I will not find a nice closed form solution.  Which is disappointing, but not terribly surprising (as, for example, the easy way to integrate powers of cosine is by using complex exponentials and the binomial theorem).